# Write some katakana combination on os X with kotoeri

Tags: discussion

I am seeking the keystroke required to write correctly the following katakanas :

- WO as in スター・**ウォ**ーズ (Star **Wa**rs from english)
- TI as in **ティ**ラミス (**ti**ramisù from italiano )
- DI as in **ディ**ズニー (**Di**sney from english)
- TU as in ブルー**トゥ**ース (Blue**too**th from english)
- DU as in ブー**ドゥ**ー (Voo**doo** from fon or ewe languages)
- SI as in メル**スィ** (mer**ci** from french)
- ZI as in トロワ**ズィ**エム (troi**si**ème from french)

I have copy pasted example to give a context.

Comment: For ティ/ディ you can (probably) use `thi` and  `dhi` as well as `teli`/`texi` and `deli` / `dexi`. For the others, type `x` or `l` before the letter you want.

Comment: ``thi`` and ``dhi`` work. thanks as well as prefixing by x to minor the vowel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Kotoeri exactly, but in the Microsoft Windows Japanese IME, you type an 'x' before letters you want to make small.

e.g. xi --> ィ　
xo --> ォ　
xu --> ゥ

Comment: it works. ありがとうございます　！

Answer (score 1):

You can write the small characters by prefacing the vowel with X.

So the small オ is `xo`, small イ is `xi` and so on.

Comment: it works. ありがとうございます　！