# How to type small hiragana/katakana, general 'keyboard tips'

Tags: discussion

I recently picked up japanese and I struggle with the japanese typesetting.

I can swith the keyboard from japanese to english, and I am new to that.
How can I type a small つ　for example?

Or how can I swap easily between the several types to be more efficient when I type vocabulary to learn?

I do that with my mouse and that is really annoying and time consuming to swap all the time between roman letters, hiragana, katakana and so on.

Any tips?
Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1620/9831 / https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1955/9831

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try typing an `x` before whatever kana you want small, like `xtsu` and `xa` give you `っ` and `ぁ`.

To switch keyboards, on Windows you can hit `Win + SPACE`, then `Ctrl + CAPSLOCK` gives hiragana, and `Alt + CAPSLOCK` gives katakana. To write in romaji just type the first letter in upper case (not sure if there is a shortcut to switch to romaji, I never use IME to write romaji).

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by 'full case' and 'IME'?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "uppercase". IME are editors which allows to enter different alphabets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method. There are several (Windows's and Google's, for example), you have to check for your operating system and find whichever suits you.

Comment: @Cornman Most of the time you don't need to type っ at all. If you double the consonant of the following character it will be added automatically, e.g. かった is typed as 'ka**tt**a',やっぱり is 'ya**pp**ari'.

Comment: If it it easier to remember [at least for me it is!], instead of "X", go for "L" as in "Little" instead (the L key, no need to make upper case). so similarly ltsu, la etc.